# 2 JSF/Richfaces versions in same app server

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces, weblogic

In the same weblogic application server, if we host 2 diff ui with 2 different JSF/Richfaces version would it work fine or will there be any classloader exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you separate the 2 UI into different .ear/.war files there should be no problem as you can do something like this in your weblogic-application.xml to specify preferred packages:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
   <package-name>org.apache.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

You can also try using the weblogic.xml to force what classes get loaded like:

```
<container-descriptor>     
   <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>   
</container-descriptor>
```

See more info here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/programming/classloading.html